# How to pass value from HTML to a ASPX files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, variables

I have the following code in my HTML file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        debugger;
        var checkedvalue = "";
        var arrChecks = document.getElementsByName("theCheckbox");

        for (i = 0; i < arrChecks.length; i++) 
        {
            // if the current state is checked, unchecked and vice-versa
            if (arrChecks[i].checked) {
                arrChecks[i].checked = false;
            } else {
                arrChecks[i].checked = true;
                checkedvalue = checkedvalue + " " + arrChecks[i].getAttribute('value');
            }

        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = checkedvalue;
    }


    function makeCheckboxes(str) {
        var a = document.getElementById("blah");
        var arr = str;
        var returnStr = "";
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            returnStr += '<input type="checkbox" name="theCheckbox" value="' + arr[i] + '" />' + arr[i];
        }
        a.innerHTML = returnStr;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var arrt = ["test1", "test2", "apple", "samsung", "nokia"];

        makeCheckboxes(arrt);
    };

</script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <td id="blah"></td>
         <td>checkboxes should appear left of here</td>
         <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
      </tr>
   </table>

         <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

So, how do I pass the value from a single HTML file to a ASPX file, which is build to store the values from the single HTML file to a database?

Suppose the user check the checkbox for `test1`, `test2` and `nokia` and click on the `Click me` button. The variable `samsung` and `apple` will be transfer to a ASPX file and store as a variable, which I can later store into a database.

For your info, I do not wish to pass the variable information using the URL to the aspx file. (e.g. http://website.com/info.aspx?var=samsung&var=apple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a sample of html page send a variable to aspx page and in cs file of aspx page you can use the coming variables from html page normally
in cs code of aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = Request.Form.Get("param1");
        }
```

in HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        myFunction = function() {
            var txtValue = document.getElementById("mytxt" ).value;
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx",
                    data:"param1=" + txtValue ,
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(msg) {
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }

        };


    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td id="blah">
                <input id="mytxt" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Redirect" onclick="myFunction()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, your second answer is much better. By the way, may I know which book that teach you the code that you provide?

Comment: it's not a book i get that code from search experience :) but any way u can try this book advanced javascript "Chuck Easttom" most people said it's amazing but i didn't read it :)

Answer (score 0):

in ur HTML file make a Javascript tag and put this code on it

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../YourAspxpath/yourAspxFile.aspx",
            data: { param1: "value", param2: "value" },
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (msg) {
                //do what ever you wnt here in case of success
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

Comment: May I know how `yourAspxFile.aspx` can read the variable values?

Comment: now in the page load of aspxfile.cs use Request.Form(param1) , Request.Form(param2)

Comment: I am getting the following error `Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.Form' cannot be used like a method.` Is it that I have to copy all the HTML code into the ASPX file so that the CS file will be able to read them? (e.g. I have to copy all the code from the HTML file into myaspxfile.aspx so that myaspxfile.cs can run them?)

Comment: it also give the error `The name 'param1' does not exist in the current`

Comment: i've added a new answer check it